# Помогите, пожалуйста, с jquery

Tags: jquery

Всем привет, всегда находил ответы в инете на свои вопросы, сейчас не могу. В общем так: есть количество товара редактируемое кнопками + и -, количество находится в type="text", нужно сделать так чтобы при количестве 1 кнопка - была недоступна, а для количества >1 доступна. Для 1 записи я решил так

```
$('#plus').click(function(){
    val=parseInt($('#kolichestvo').val());
    val2= val + 1;
    $('#kolichestvo').val(val2);

    if (val2>1){ $('#minus').removeAttr('disabled'); }
});

$('#minus').click(function(){
    val=parseInt($('#kolichestvo').val());
    val2= val - 1;
    $('#kolichestvo').val(val2);
    if (val2<=1){ $('#minus').attr('disabled','disabled'); }

});
<button id="minus" disabled>-</button>
<input type="text" value="1" id="kolichestvo" disabled>
<button id="plus">+</button>
```

а как сделать если у меня потом количество и каждая кнопка выводится циклом из БД, то есть так

```
do {

echo <button id="minus">-</button><input id="kolichestvo" type="text" value="'.$data['kolichestvo'].'" disabled size="1"><button id="plus">+</button></td> } while ($data=  mysql_fetch_assoc($zapros));
```

нужно чтобы кнопки + и - работали только с тем полем, которое выводится вместе с ними. Спасибо.

Comment: minus = dec (decrеment, отнять единицу)

    plus = inc (incrеment, прибавить единицу)

    kolichestvo = sum

    $zapros = $query, $request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Привязку можно реализовать так, так же как и статус кнопки ещё на выводе.

```
<?php

do {
    if($data['kolichestvo']==1)$button_state = 'disable';
print(
        '<button id="minus" target="'.$data['id'].'" '.$button_state.' >-</button>'.
        '<input id="kolichestvo" type="text" name="'.$data['id'].'" value="'.$data['kolichestvo'].'" size="1">'.
        '<button id="plus"target="'.$data['id'].'" >+</button>'.
);
    echo  
}while ($data=  mysql_fetch_assoc($zapros));
```

И соответственно потом в JS обрабатывать.

```
$('#minus').click(function(){
    var id = this.getAttr('target'); //точно не помню имя функции.
    var val = parseInt($('#kolichestvo [name='+id+']').val())-1;
    $('#kolichestvo [name='+id+']').val(val);
    if(val==1){
        this.attr('disable','true')
    }
});

$('#plus').click(function(){
    var id = this.getAttr('target');
    var val = parseInt($('#kolichestvo [name='+id+']').val())+1;
    $('#kolichestvo [name='+id+']').val(val);
    if(val!=1){
        $('#minus [target='+id+']').removeAttr('disable') 
    }
});
```